# Tricky constraint combining 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints, combinations

I need to be sure about integrity of data in MSSQL database. My data model contains two important fields which are foreign keys to another tables. For example TripId and ReservationId (random names so don't bother about them).

I need the ability to insert data if: 
- ReservationId and TripId are not null
- ReservationId is null and TripId is not null
-ReservationId is not null and TripId is null

It is tricky, because I need to reject inserts when one of Id was used in antoher combination, so for example:
My db contains record with RES111 and TRIP666. I must be able to insert another record with the same Ids for reservation and trip.
I mustn't insert data which contains only one ReservationId or TripId or another combination( for example reject: RES111 and TRIP777 must be rejected)

The same when one Id is provided, for example ReservationId.
Inserts containing used ReservationId with any tripId must be rejected.

I can provide such filtering in application code but it has to be done on database level

Comment: Please provide us some code, "us" coders are better at reading code then reading plain English, also provide some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I think you'll need a trigger for this.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, I don't think constraints can handle this kind of complexity

Comment: So, by itself `ReservationId` has to be unique (except for multiple `NULL`s)? And the same for `TripId`?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a conditional insert

For Example

```
insert into tblname (value, name) 
select 'foo', 'bar'
where not exists (select 1 from table where null IN (ReservationId, TripId));
```

Of course you will need to tailor this to what you need exactly.

The basic concept is, as long as the subquery returns a result, the insert will happen, so the subquery can be a really complicated constrained or check.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this either with a Trigger, or with a CHECK CONSTRAINT that calls a UDF that encapsulates the logic you want to enforce.